How to know which code is injecting my DI service?
In C# with typical dependency injection services setup. I have my own custom service registered and it works fine. However, I find it is being injected more than expected, and I don't know why / due to what code. So I want to debug and know what code wants my service to be injected? I can't figure out how to do that.
Example:
// Program startup I register my service as normal.
services.AddTransient<MyCustomService>();
// And other stuff...
services.AddTransient<SomeOtherThing>();
services.AddTransient<AndAnother>();
services.AddTransient<AndMore>();

public class MyCustomService
{
    public MyCustomService()
    {
        // My service works fine, but can it know who is requesting it?
        // WHO IS REQUESTING ME FROM DI?

        // Note that this is not intended for some weird hacky functionality,
        // rather I'm trying to debug why my service is being injected more than expected.
    }
}

// Some other services/controllers/etc that are pulling in MyCustomService from DI
...
    public SomeOtherThing(MyCustomService mcs) { ... }
...
    public AndAnother(MyCustomService mcs) { ... }
...
    public AndMore(MyCustomService mcs) { ... }
...

To clarify:
Some code asks the DI service-provider to create something (eg SomeOtherThing). In order to create SomeOtherThing it needs to first create MyCustomService. So the service-provider creates MyCustomService - and here is where I have my breakpoint, how would I then inspect the service-provider (or something) to know that SomeOtherThing (in this example) is the one who wants to consume MyCustomService?

What do you mean by "times that I didn't expect"?

Your usage of "invoke" and "inject" is a little bit confusing. The DI container is the party that injects MyCustomService to all the classes that make use of it, and it injects it only during the start up of your application with the statement services.AddTransient<MyCustomService>(). On the other hand, I take it that by "invoke" you actually mean "call", i.e. from what class is your suspicious method in MyCustomService being called. "Invoke" is for events.

There might be other DI Containers that allow object graphs to be queried or visualized. Such feature, however, does not exist for the built-in container, MS.DI.

So I could not find an "easy" way of inspecting the service provider (or something else) to know (at runtime) what other code has caused DI to create "MyCustomService".
However, there is a simple/obvious solution: just step through the DI code until we come out the other end, into the instantiation of that other code we want to know about. This isn't particularly convenient, and it can fail if there are exceptions/etc along the line.. but it did end up working for my case.

Note that in my situation, where "MyCustomService" instantiation was throwing exceptions, I had to conditionally catch/throw the exception in order to cause the exceptional chain of events, while then NOT throwing on the next instantiation so that I could step through (the DI code) and figure out what was consuming my service. This was inconvenient and I spent a bunch of time that could have been saved if there was a tool that just said "service X is the one that wants service Y" somehow. Looking at the DI code it seems like this should be possible, maybe there is already a tool out there that does this? I didn't find it though :(

Put a breakpoint inside of your service. When the breakpoint is hit at those unexpected times, check the call stack to find out the origin of the call to your service.
Following your example, put your breakpoint inside the relevant method in MyCustomService, and then look for appearances of either SomeOtherThing.SomeMethod(), AndAnother.AnotherMethod() or  AndMore.AndMoreMethod() in the call stack list to find out the culprit.
If you have VS Enterprise you can even check the call stack as a visual map.

"check the call stack to find out the origin of the call to your service." I'm afraid that won't work. The consuming component (e.g. SomeOtherThing)  will not be in the callstack, as its code (its ctor) hasn't yet been called at the point that its dependencies are created or resolved.

@Steven Thanks for your input. Perhaps I should have stated clearly "put your breakpoint inside the relevant method, not the constructor, that is being called at unexpected times". We definitely need more clarification as to what does OP exactly mean with "I find [my service] is being invoked (injected) at times that I didn't expect".

As @Steven mentions, having a breakpoint in MyCustomService is too early in the chain of events to see anything useful in the call stack. I want to know which code (eg SomeOtherThing, AnotherThing, SomethingIDontKnowAbout, etc) is requesting MyCustomService from the DI container, at runtime. Such that if DI service provider is requested to create SomeOtherService, and it creates MyCustomService first (in order to pass to SomeOtherService's constructor)... then if I have a breakpoint in MyCustomService, how could I tell what code wants to 'consume' MyCustomService?

@devlop thanks for your further explanations, I think I finally could understand your problem. In any case, and just out of curiosity, what use is determining the service that requested the injection in this way? In the end, you are going to make use of the services through their particular methods for which it should be easy to verify the origin of the calls... or maybe I am very wrong about this all.

While the classes themselves should not care about who they're using and by whom they are used, as a developer I regularly find it very helpful to get an understanding of the object graphs being built, especially when I'm not yet that familiar with a (certain part of a) code base. This is why some DI Containers contain features to visualize this. Some have an API for this, or allow to see this information in the debugger, or both. With MS.DI, you can (partly) get this information, but you will have to write this code yourself.

@jarmanso7 in my case I had a service ("MyCustomService") that is pulled in from DI by many pieces of code. It was throwing an exception on instantiation (in a certain situation) more often than I expected. I wanted to know what code was pulling in the service from DI (and causing the exception). I was able to hack my code to swallow the exceptions conditionally which then allowed me to step through DI code and find the 'consumer' sources - but it was a time-draining hassle.

Hi @devlop: if your code throws an exception while resolving/retrieving instances from the DI Container, for -any- other reason than a misconfiguration (e.g. missing dependency) in your DI container, your code does too much during object construction. Your injection constructors should be simple.

@Steven Yes I agree, expecting service injection to throw is not a good pattern. It shouldn't be throwing. It's a domain/legacy situation we have that needs re-architecting - which is part of why I'm trying to understand the current code. Thanks :)
